# $(...).masonry is not a function Laravel JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, masonry

Downloaded `masonry.min.js` and required it in my js file, than wrote

```
$('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
  });
```

and it's bringing the error `$(...).masonry is not a function`, I'm using laravel blades but I don't think there should be a difference :/

[image]

and here is the error

[image]

[image]

`<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>`
`<script src="{{url("/js/app.js")}}"></script>`
in `layout.blade.php` which is my layout and is used everywhere

Comment: If I am not confused, you are using `require` but you cannot use that without importing it in your `mix` JS final file... also, I think you should use `import` instead of `require` but the problem is in that part...

Comment: Where should I import it? where are that mix files? I required everything in my `app.js` which is working, the other required js files are working that way, why is not working the masonry one?

Comment: Mmmmmmmmm, then I am not sure... I am more used to using Vue or React than having separate things and use `require`, I mostly use `import` but with jQuery I think you have to use `require`... Where is your `masonry.min.js` being imported at ? Are you using Laravel Mix `bootstrap.js` ? Are you saving that file in a place where it is accesible by URL so you put a `<script>` with it in your `head` or `body` ? Can you show that part please ?

Comment: I used both, and I required it in the working `app.js` and I wrote a `<script src="http://...">` in my layour's `head` none is working, and when I try in a simple `html css js` file testing it, it's working perfectly

Comment: Can you share your `webpack.mix.js` and the content of the files you are using there ?

Comment: Can you show us where is your `<script ....>` and how it is ? I think the problem is there. Also show us where is your `<script src=...>` for `app.js`. And please, do not share images, copy paste your code

Comment: I have edited it again please check

Comment: I am not sure now, I think the problem is that `require('./masonry.min.js')` will do nothing, where is that defined ? Nowhere, that is the problem... You should download the file you are trying to use, add it as a `require` to your `masonry.js` (you are already doing this), and then save the download file as `masonry.min.js` where it can be accessed like the other `require`s. That way, when you compile the file with Laravel Mix, it should work...

Comment: No, I did that what you told, I've downloaded it, I have also tried requireing it in my main `app.js` and in app.js wrote the masonry code, it brought the same problem

Comment: The thing is that you need to have `jquery` already loaded when you want to require that plugin. If you are not going to share `webpack.mix.js` and your `layout.blade.php` it will be harder to test...